# ART internal storage problm

Tags: android-versions

Using my moto e in Art mode and my internal memory is totally consumed will I get my internal memory if I switch again to dalvik?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will get your memory back.

During the reboot process, Android will have to optimize all apps, so this will take some time. About 15 min. to 60 min. for this to complete, that all depends on how many apps you have. Make sure you device is fully charged.

---

You also can manually edit the file with runtime values, which is located: */data/property/persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib*

libart.so and libdvm.so are the values.

Command:

> *adb shell 'echo libdvm.so >/data/property/persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib'*

Or

> *adb shell setprop persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib libdvm.so*